# Lit-element - Importing a component inside another component and then accessing the DOM of the imported component

Tags: javascript, web, components, lit-element, flatpickr

I've honestly racked my brain on this for a couple days. I'm decently new to **lit-element** and web components in general.

Basically, I'm building a new component called `<date-picker>` and it uses the Flatpickr plugin. This Date Picker component imports another component called `<textfield>`. Inside of that component there is a wrapper(.date-picker) with an input field and an icon. I need to be able to access the wrapper so I can click the input field and icon to trigger the calendar popup. But no matter what I do, I can't reach those the dom elements inside the component. I've tried accessing them using `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.date-picker')` along with the light dom `document.querySelector('.date-picker')` among a variety of other things. Sample code below. I appreciate any insight you can offer.

**Date picker component:**

```
render() {
  return html`
    <textfield iconalt="Calendar" iconname="calendar" label="Calendar" optionaltext="hide"></textfield>
  `;
}

updated() {
  var datePickerShadow = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.date-picker'); // gets el in shadow dom
  var datePickerLight = document.querySelector('.date-picker'); // gets el in light dom

  var importantDate = [Date.parse('2021-1-27'), Date.parse('2021-1-5'), Date.parse('2021-2-9')];
    var datePicker = flatpickr(datePickerLight, {
        wrap: true,
        disable: ["2021-01-30", "2021-01-21", "2021-01-08", new Date(2025, 4, 9) ],
        allowInput: true,
        clickOpens: false,
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<textfield>` is a custom element then its tagname is illegal: custom element tags [must contain](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#valid-custom-element-name) at least a `-`. This is probably preventing the browser from [upgrading](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-upgrades-examples) it (and thus rendering its content and executing its logic).

Anyway if `.date-picker` is inside of `<textfield>`'s template, neither of the `querySelector` calls you tried would work: the first selects inside `<date-picker>`'s shadow dom but does not recurse in child components, while the second completely misses shadow doms.

What you can do is:

- Use cascaded querySelectors

  ```js
  class DatePicker extends LitElement {

    async firstUpdated() {
      const textField = this.renderRoot.querySelector('text-field');
      await textField.updated; // Wait for first render of text-field
      const datePicker = textField.renderRoot.querySelector('.date-picker');
    }

  }
  ```
- Move `.date-picker` in `<date-picker>`'s template if possible
- Pass `.date-picker` to `<text-field>` which renders it in a [slot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots)

  ```js
  // This way you can directly select .date-picker

  render() {
    return html`
      <text-field>
        <div class="date-picker"></div>
      </text-field>
    `;
  }
  ```
- Instantiate the picker inside `<text-field>` and expose the instance using a property (or part of its functionality through methods and properties).

(I'd avoid the first option if possible)

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try this and get back. You’re right. The component name has been modified just because this is something I ran into at work. I’ll follow up. Thanks again

Comment: Ultimately I ended up using a combination of Umbo's solution and a custom event to achieve what I needed. Thanks again for the assist!